# Toggle buttons not displaying true state in CMS - Umbraco 9

Tags: angular, iis, content-management-system, toggle, umbraco

In the CMS, for the toggle buttons, aria-checked is not being set to true when the value is true, and the class "umb-toggle--checked" is not being applied to the button. I have successfully ported our Umbraco 8 build to Umbraco 9, and up until now running locally, and running as localhost, this problem has not occurred, but now I run in dev and test (https) the issue is happening and you cannot tell if a button is on or off.

Please see image below, the toggle buttons are not rendering correctly, the button below is set to on(true). I can change/display content, but you cannot visually see any change in the CMS. There are no console errors but I wondered are there any permissions that need to be set that I am unaware of. I have also added the static content mimeMaps to the IIS web config.

[image]

The same button in a Macro in the settings area in Umbraco 9 or Umbraco 8

Toggle button code on Umbraco 9 in IIS

```
<button role="checkbox" aria-checked="" ng-click="click()" type="button" class="umb-toggle ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'umb-toggle--checked': checked, 'umb-toggle--disabled': disabled}" id="umb-toggle_b4defe77-f89c-4573-a2f9-02d27627f731" checked="checked" on-click="model.toggle('useInEditor')">
```

Toggle button code in Umbraco 9 running as Localhost in Visual Studio

```
<button role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" ng-click="click()" type="button" class="umb-toggle ng-scope ng-isolate-scope umb-toggle--checked" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'umb-toggle--checked': checked, 'umb-toggle--disabled': disabled}" id="umb-toggle_d4e9f676-a371-4e31-8185-190125aaf92e" checked="checked" on-click="model.toggle('useInEditor')">
```

Toggle button code in Umbraco 8 in IIS

```
<button role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" ng-click="click()" type="button" class="umb-toggle umb-toggle--checked" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'umb-toggle--checked': checked, 'umb-toggle--disabled': disabled}" id="umb-toggle_2a994d42-c01b-46f8-a8e8-3b3a7ea5a901" checked="checked" on-click="model.toggle('useInEditor')">
```

What is the Angular JavaScript that changes the state of the toggle buttons and where do I start to look or has someone had the same issue?

Thank you in advance for any help in resolving this issue, I cannot put Umbraco 9 in to production as a complete replacement for Umbraco 8 until this has been resolved.

Kind regards
Pete

Answer (score 1):

The AttributeQuotesRemovalMode didn't resolve this for me on Umbraco 10.3.2 with WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore6 2.12.0 .

In the end I went with ignoring the whole Umbraco directory:

```
            services.AddWebMarkupMin(options =>
            {
                options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;

            })
            .AddHtmlMinification(options =>
            {
                
                options.ExcludedPages = new List<IUrlMatcher>
                    {
                        new WildcardUrlMatcher("/umbraco/*"),
                    };
            })
```

See: https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/ASP.NET-Core-6

Answer (score 0):

I’m thinking there could be some caching issues here, if the cache has remnants of Umbraco 8 it might confuse things. If not that then I’d suggest creating an issue over on https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues :-/

Comment: Hi Jannik, thank you for your feedback. I tried with a new empty database as well, since I thought the same as you, but the same issue occurred. I will certainly consider putting in an issue as per your suggestion. Kind regards, Pete

Answer (score 0):

It was discovered that this issue was caused by a setting in WebMarkUpMin for .NET CORE not being present in the startup.cs options:

```
options.MinificationSettings.AttributeQuotesRemovalMode = HtmlAttributeQuotesRemovalMode.KeepQuotes;
```

This setting, when added resolved this issue and all on states of any toggle buttons can now be seen